# IE8 and IE9 ignores padding of submit button

Tags: css, internet-explorer, padding

Somehow IE8 and IE9 are ignoring my padding settings for a submit button. The weird thing is that IE8 and IE9 apply the padding to a regular button like

```
<a class="btn" href="#">foo<a>
```

But not for

```
<input type="submit">
```

How is this possible? I've read something about adding overflow:visible but that doesn't work.

This is the CSS that I'm using:

```
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background: #74ad38;
padding: 10px 20px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px rgba(99, 148, 48, 1);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 6px 0px rgba(99, 148, 48, 1);
box-shadow:         0px 6px 0px rgba(99, 148, 48, 1);
border-radius: 5px;
border: none;
transition: background 0.25s;
-moz-transition: background 0.25s;
-webkit-transition: background 0.25s;
-ms-transition: background 0.25s;
-o-transition: background 0.25s;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The selector you are using is what?  It looks like it works to me:  http://jsfiddle.net/74vNM/

Comment: These selectors am I using input[type="submit"], input[type="button"]

Comment: Have you tried `padding: 10px 20px !important;` ?

Comment: Nope, but that seems to be the trick. Thanks!